# Count number of character and their position until a value is reached

Tags: r, vector, counting

I need to sum the number of times, starting from the last value, that the `r` element appears in my vector until it reaches an `a` element. For example, suppose I have a vector `V = c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r' , 0, 'r')`.
Note that in this case, the number of times that the element `r` appears until appears an `a` is 2 times. So I would need a to return the number 2 to me, in addition to bringing up the positions at which they appear, ie, position `13` and `11`. Something like

```
> some.function(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r' , 0, 'r'))
[1] 2
[2] 13 
[3] 11

> some.function(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r'))
[1] 1
[2] 11

> some.function(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r'))
[1] 3
[2] 7
[3] 5
[4] 4

> some.function(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 0))
[1] 3
[2] 7
[3] 5
[4] 4
```

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: This question would be substantially improved with more example cases and expected outputs. Additional details about the positions returned would also be helpful. What if there are 3 `'a'`'s after the first `'r'` followed by an `'a'`?

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I read it as `the number of times that the element appears`, but it also says position.  Not clear

Comment: Ok, I'll prepare a figure to try to explain better what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option (based on the examples showed)

1. Use a group by operation - `tapply`
2. Create the group based on a logical vector (`x == 'a'`) with [`rleid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/rleid)
3. Pass the `X` in `tapply` with the sequence of input vector (`seq_along(x)`) multiplie dby the logical vector (`x == 'r'`) so that we get positions corresponding to 'r' while the others i.e. FALSE will be 0.
4. Specify the lambda function in `FUN` to subset elements that are not 0
5. The above step 4 returns some `list` elements with `length` 0 as those were only having 0 values and we subset
6. Use `Filter` to remove those empty `list` elements
7. Get the `last` element with `tail`, and specify the `n = 1`
8. Append with the `length` of the extracted element and return that as function output

```
f1 <- function(x) {

       out <- tail(Filter(length, tapply(seq_along(x) * (x == 'r'), 
             data.table::rleid(x == 'a'), FUN = function(y) y[y != 0])), 1)[[1]]
      c(length(out), out)
        
}
```

-testing

```
lapply(lst1, f1)
[[1]]
[1]  2 11 13

[[2]]
[1]  1 11

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 7
```

NOTE: Just for testing purpose, the vectors were created as `list`.  Can also do this on a single vector

```
f1(lst1[[1]])
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c("a", "0", "a", "r", "r", "0", "r", "a", "0", "a", "r", 
"0", "r"), c("a", "0", "a", "r", "r", "0", "r", "a", "0", "a", 
"r"), c("a", "0", "a", "r", "r", "0", "r"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked all the cases (although by eye it seems as though my code should work), nor embedded the code in the function, but this logic seems to do the trick.

```r
## setup
x <- c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r' , 0, 'r')
## find all 'r' locations
xpos <- which(x == "r")
## reverse
rx <- rev(x)
## truncate at first occurrence of 'a'
trx <- rx[seq(min(which(rx=="a")))]
## count number of 'r' values
nr <- sum(trx=="r")
## find last (nr) 'r' values in the sequence
rr <- rev(xpos)[seq(nr)]
```

This will probably break in some edge cases (no "r" at all in the vector, no "r" preceded by an "a", etc., no "a" at all ...)

Answer (score 1):

one more approach

```r
somefunc <- function(x){
  y <- which(max(cumsum(x == 'a')) == cumsum(x == 'a') & x == 'r')
  return(c(length(y), rev(y)))
}

somefunc(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r' , 0, 'r'))
#> [1]  2 13 11
somefunc(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 'a', 0, 'a', 'r'))
#> [1]  1 11
somefunc(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r'))
#> [1] 3 7 5 4
somefunc(c('a', 0, 'a', 'r', 'r', 0, 'r', 0))
#> [1] 3 7 5 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>